# How to make a segue by a tableViewDelegate

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, segue

I'd like to create a segue from a tableViewDelegate cell to an other view. This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class CoriViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var elencoCori : SquadraModel! //This var contains label and array

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    InterfaceManager.sharedInstance.putBlurBackgroundToTableView(self.view, tableView: self.tableView)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.elencoCori.cori.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
    let coro = elencoCori.cori[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = coro.marker
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDettaglioController", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now the problem: how I could set a prepareForSegue that send to the secondView? In other circumstances I would have solved the problem like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "toDettaglioController"
    {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! Dettaglio controller
            controller.coro = elencoCori.cori[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

but I know the this doesn't work and I have to use a delegate method. So can everyone help me with a step-by-step guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method call `performSegueWithIdentifier` and pass the `indexPath` as your sender.

Then in `prepareForSegue` you can do `if let indexPath = sender as NSIndexPath` and setup your controller.

Comment: yeah it works perfectly, except for a little "bug". When I have access for the rest time to the controller I cannot click on the cell... please see this video for a more precise explanation. https://www.dropbox.com/s/or52efq9qmdnlr6/errore.mov?dl=0

Comment: That's odd, but I doubt it's related to the way you are doing the segue.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have One UITableViewController-**T** and Two UIViewControllers-**A and B**.

Now suppose you want to go from **T** to **A** when **cell 0** is clicked,
 and go from **T** to **B** when **cell 1** is clicked.

**Step 1 :** Connect segue from **T to A** and name that segue "segueToA"
**Step 2 :** Connect segue from **T to B** and name that segue "segueToB"
**Step 3 :** Got to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in **T** and put `if-else`

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToA", sender: nil)
}else{
   self. performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToB", sender: nil)
}
```

That's it.

**Update:** Here is a  [Sample Project.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/05gtpqfyejn6c6y/TableViewSegue.zip?dl=0)

Comment: sorry, but in the storyboard I don't have any cell, because I'm working on a UITableControllerDelegate, so I made the segue directly from the controller (yellow square in the top of the view in the storyboard)

Comment: You can do this without cell, by just connecting tableview with your viewcontrollers.